# Npm throw an error after update to nodejs 8

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

After I update my nodejs to the latest version I always get error when trying to run `npm install` to install packages:

```
npm WARN registry Using stale data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/escope failed,      reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I don't have any issues with my internet connection and I disable the route to https: https://registry.npmjs.org and replace it with http - the first install worked and right after start not working again.

node version `8.2.1`

npm version `5.3.0`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it's helps to anyone: The only solution that works for me is to ping registry to find the IP. and the fact I have got the IP means I am not blocked

`ping registry.npmjs.org`

`64 bytes from registry.npmjs.org (151.101.60.162): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=87.3 ms`

Set the IP to this host on my hosts file (Im in centos /etc/hosts/):

`151.101.60.162 registry.npmjs.org`

I am almost sure it's some glitch in NPM

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me! Just a question here. Do I have to worry about removing host entry later?

Comment: In 2019 this error is still here and the solution still works

Answer (score 16):

You may want to check your NPM proxy settings and perhaps remove it.

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

One might expect a fresh install of NodeJS+NPM would not have a proxy configured. Strangely enough, mine did come with a proxy defined, pointing to an IP and port 3128. Removing the proxy did the trick.

Comment: No - it's not it - I get nuill when i do get proxy. Thanks

Comment: try, npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/  . OR, Check  your ISP's or Company's firewall/proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Set the proxy as written below in your command prompt.

```
npm config set proxy http://1X.XX.X.40:80
```

It solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I try the first solution, ping registry.npmjs.org and add it to host file , not work, and I try the second way :

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

And that work for me.
With "npm config get proxy" i had a value with port 8080 now it's null.

I don't know where that value comme from.